# Twig - Rendering a variable

Tags: php, twig

I am rendering a template file, in which I have a variable {{page_content|raw}}. This all works fine. However I want to render that variable as twig... the value contents more variables in which I want to parse using the same environment.

I am using PHP.

Comment: please re-phrase your question; i don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Do mean the `{{ page_content }}` variable itself contains other `twig` tags?

Comment: Yes. I mean just that. I'm sorry, I'm a native English but I'm very poor with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `template_from_string` function.

See the documentation [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html).

> `Twig_Loader_String` loads templates from strings. It's a dummy loader as the template reference is the template source code

It seems to be necessary to explicitly say you want to use it as seen in the first link:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment(...);
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());
```

Also possible directly in your twig template (first link)

```
{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}") }}
{{ include(template_from_string(page_content)) }}
```